# Java Swing - MIDI Piano First Steps

Tags: java, swing

I'm only in my first stages of creating this project but I'm already lost. In my class we mainly focus on AWT, but for this project I was told to learn swing.

Right now I am experimenting with Layouts to position the keys in the right positions as a normal keyboard would. I just really need help getting my layout on point. If someone could explain and provide code that would be fantastic. Thanks

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JButton a1,a1s,b1,c1,c1s,d1,d1s,e1,f1,f1s,g1,g1s;
private JPanel panel;
private int x_pos = 50;
String title = "INTERACTIVE PIANO";    


private void createGUI()
{
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Container window = getContentPane();
  window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );

  /*  panel = new JPanel();   
  panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  panel.setLayout(null);
  panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
  window.add(panel); */
  addKeys(); 
  }

  public void addKeys()
  {
    a1 = new JButton("A"); 
    {
      a1.setBackground(Color.white);
      a1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      a1.setLayout(null);
      a1.addActionListener(this);
      add(a1);

    } 


    a1s = new JButton("A#");
    {
      a1s.setBackground(Color.black);
      a1s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
      a1s.setLayout(null);
      a1s.addActionListener(this);
      add(a1s);
    } 


    b1 = new JButton("B"); 
    {
      b1.setBackground(Color.white);
      b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      b1.setLayout(null);
      b1.addActionListener(this);
      add(b1);
    }  

    c1 = new JButton("C"); 
    {
      c1.setBackground(Color.white);
      c1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      c1.setLayout(null);
      c1.addActionListener(this);
      add(c1);
    }  

    c1s = new JButton("C#");
    {
      c1s.setBackground(Color.black);
      c1s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
      c1s.setLayout(null);
      c1s.addActionListener(this);
      add(c1s);
    } 

    d1 = new JButton("D"); 
    {
      d1.setBackground(Color.white);
      d1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      d1.setLayout(null);
      d1.addActionListener(this);
      add(d1);
    }  

    d1s = new JButton("D#");
    {
      d1s.setBackground(Color.black);
      d1s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
      d1s.setLayout(null);
      d1s.addActionListener(this);
      add(d1s);
    } 

    e1 = new JButton("E"); 
    {
      e1.setBackground(Color.white);
      e1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      e1.setLayout(null);
      e1.addActionListener(this);
      add(e1);
    } 

    f1 = new JButton("F"); 
    {
      f1.setBackground(Color.white);
      f1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      f1.setLayout(null);
      f1.addActionListener(this);
      add(f1);
    }  

    f1s = new JButton("F#");
     {
      f1s.setBackground(Color.black);
      f1s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
      f1s.setLayout(null);
      f1s.addActionListener(this);
      add(f1s);
    }  

    g1 = new JButton("G"); 
    {
      g1.setBackground(Color.white);
      g1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
      g1.setLayout(null);
      g1.addActionListener(this);
      add(g1);
    }  

    g1s = new JButton("G#");
    {
      g1s.setBackground(Color.black);
      g1s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
      g1s.setLayout(null);
      g1s.addActionListener(this);
      add(g1s);
    }  

 }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
   //  Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics(); 
   if (event.getSource() == a1)
   {

   }


  } 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  main frame = new main();
  frame.setTitle("Interactive Piano v1.0");
  frame.setSize(800, 700);
  frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
  frame.createGUI();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setLayout(null);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout managers are really designed for 2 dimensional positioning of components.

For a piano you want the black keys on top of the white keys so this is one case where you would probably want to use a null layout so you can control the positioning of each component. This means you are now responsible for setting the size/location of each component.

You would add the black keys to the panel first and then add the white keys.

I'll give you a little hint. Your main panel would look something like this:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null)
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        int count = getComponentCount();
        Component last = getComponent(count - 1);
        Rectangle bounds = last.getBounds();
        int width = 10 + bounds.x + bounds.width;
        int height = 10 + bounds.y + bounds.height;

        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Since the white keys are added last, the last component on the panel will be a white key. So this component is used to determine the preferred size of the panel to fit all the white keys.

The `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` method is overridden since components will be stacked on top of one another. This will ensure that the black keys are always painted on top of the white keys.

Answer (score 1):

Actually JLayeredPane is designed to do what you want: Overlap widgets with a prescribed z-order. Something like this:

```
package experimental;

import static experimental.Experimental.KeyColor.BLACK;
import static experimental.Experimental.KeyColor.WHITE;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Experimental {
  static final int WHITE_KEY_WIDTH = 48;
  static final int WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT = 300;
  static final int BLACK_KEY_WIDTH = 32;
  static final int BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT = 210;

  enum KeyColor { WHITE, BLACK };

  enum PitchClass {
    A("A", WHITE),
    A_SHARP("A#", BLACK),
    B("B", WHITE),
    C("C", WHITE),
    C_SHARP("C#", BLACK),
    D("D", WHITE),
    D_SHARP("D#", BLACK),
    E("E", WHITE),
    F("F", WHITE),
    F_SHARP("F#", BLACK),
    G("G", WHITE),
    G_SHARP("G#", BLACK),
    ;

    final String name;
    final KeyColor color;

    PitchClass(String name, KeyColor color) {
      this.name = name;
      this.color = color;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keyboard");
        JLayeredPane keyboard = new JLayeredPane();
        frame.add(keyboard);
        addKeys(keyboard);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(2000, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      private void addKeys(JLayeredPane keyboard) {
        int x = 0;
        int keyCount = 0;
        for (int octave = 1; ; ++octave) {
          for (PitchClass note : PitchClass.values()) {
            JButton key = new JButton(note.name);
            key.setOpaque(true);
            key.setActionCommand(String.format("%d/%s", octave, note.name));
            if (note.color == WHITE) {
              key.setBounds(x, 0, WHITE_KEY_WIDTH, WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT);
              keyboard.add(key, new Integer(0));
              x += WHITE_KEY_WIDTH;
            } else {
              key.setBounds(x - BLACK_KEY_WIDTH / 2, 0, BLACK_KEY_WIDTH, BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT);
              keyboard.add(key, new Integer(1));
            }
            key.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              @Override
              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e); 
                if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                  System.out.println("Press: "+ ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand());
                }
              }
              @Override
              public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseReleased(e);
                if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                  System.out.println("Release: "+ ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand());
                }
              }
            });
            if (++keyCount == 40) return;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```